# ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0: Adding custom flags for a specific user and access them by another user

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

I am a noob in asp.net identity and I am creating roles using this code snippet

```
var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "UserType1", "UserType2"};
            IdentityResult roleResult;

            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
                if (!roleExist)
                {
                    //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1
                    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                }
            }
```

Now i want to set a flag which would be only for user 1 and that would be approved by the admin only. For instance, `config.SignIn.IsApprovedByAdmin=true`(only for user1) and How can admin approve it for User1? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Identity Server 4.

Comment: yes, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add new property to user with ASP.NET Core Identity  :

[How to extend ASP.NET Core Identity user](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html)

So that you could update that property for specific user , and users who has admin role could query/filter user base on that property , and approve/update property value .